# adb backups fail with "Internal exception during full backup"

Tags: cyanogenmod, adb, backup

For a while now, I've not been able to create a full `adb backup` of my Nexus 4.

Now finally I've been able to catch a slightly more useful error report with logcat:

```
D/BackupManagerService( 2061): Calling doFullBackup() on de.blinkt.openvpn
I/file_backup_helper( 9115):    Name: apps/de.blinkt.openvpn/r/app_webview
I/file_backup_helper( 9115):    Name: apps/de.blinkt.openvpn/r/app_webview/Web Data-journal
I/file_backup_helper( 9115):    Name: apps/de.blinkt.openvpn/r/app_webview/Web Data
I/file_backup_helper( 9115):    Name: apps/de.blinkt.openvpn/r/app_webview/paks
I/file_backup_helper( 9115):    Name: apps/de.blinkt.openvpn/f/8b8192c9-4aa3-42b3-affb-fd49fc7044d7.vp
I/file_backup_helper( 9115):    Name: apps/de.blinkt.openvpn/sp/WebViewChromiumPrefs.xml
I/file_backup_helper( 9115):    Name: apps/de.blinkt.openvpn/sp/activities.LogWindow.xml
I/file_backup_helper( 9115):    Name: apps/de.blinkt.openvpn/sp/de.blinkt.openvpn_preferences.xml
I/file_backup_helper( 9115):    Name: apps/de.blinkt.openvpn/sp/VPNList.xml
I/art     ( 2268): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/art     ( 2288): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/art     ( 2717): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
I/art     ( 2061): Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 217771(9MB) AllocSpace objects, 32(1594KB) LOS objects, 33% fr
ee, 29MB/44MB, paused 2.136ms total 158.660ms
E/BackupManagerService( 2061): Internal exception during full backup
E/BackupManagerService( 2061): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=32768; regionStart=0; regionLength=-1
E/BackupManagerService( 2061):  at java.util.Arrays.checkOffsetAndCount(Arrays.java:1719)
E/BackupManagerService( 2061):  at java.util.zip.DeflaterOutputStream.write(DeflaterOutputStream.java:174)
E/BackupManagerService( 2061):  at com.android.server.backup.BackupManagerService.routeSocketDataToOutput(BackupManagerSe
rvice.java:3135)
E/BackupManagerService( 2061):  at com.android.server.backup.BackupManagerService.access$900(BackupManagerService.java:15
8)
E/BackupManagerService( 2061):  at com.android.server.backup.BackupManagerService$FullBackupEngine.backupOnePackage(Backu
pManagerService.java:3271)
E/BackupManagerService( 2061):  at com.android.server.backup.BackupManagerService$PerformAdbBackupTask.run(BackupManagerS
ervice.java:3849)
E/BackupManagerService( 2061):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
D/BackupManagerService( 2061): Full backup processing complete.
D/bu      ( 6589): Finished.
D/AndroidRuntime( 6589): Shutting down VM
D/BackupManagerService( 2061): Full backup pass complete.
```

I'm running CyanogenMod `12.1-20151007-SNAPSHOT-YOG4PAO334-mako`. This problem started a few releases earlier though.

My Android file system is encrypted. I usually run the backup like this:

```
adb backup -apk -shared -system -all -f "adb-backup.$(date +"%Y%m%d").ab"
```

Any ideas?

(BTW, I think the fact that OpenVPN was being backed up just before the issue is probably a red herring)

Answer (score 2):

While I was typing up the question I managed to finish a full backup. I used the `-nocompress` flag (which isn't documented in the help for `adb`), and used the same passphrase for the backup as for my Android file system encryption.

So, this was the full command:

```
adb backup -nocompress -apk -shared -system -all -f "adb-backup.$(date +"%Y%m%d").ab"
```

logcat:

```
...
I/file_backup_helper( 6652):    Name: shared/0/0/Ringtones
I/file_backup_helper( 6652):    Name: shared/0/0/Ringtones/hangouts_incoming_call.ogg
I/file_backup_helper( 6652):    Name: shared/0/0/Ringtones/hangouts_video_call.ogg
I/file_backup_helper( 6652):    Name: shared/0/0/Ringtones/hangouts_message.ogg
I/file_backup_helper( 6652):    Name: shared/0/0/Podcasts
I/file_backup_helper( 6652):    Name: shared/0/0/Music
D/BackupManagerService( 2061): Full package backup success: com.android.sharedstoragebackup
D/BackupManagerService( 2061): Full backup processing complete.
D/bu      ( 9722): Finished.
D/AndroidRuntime( 9722): Shutting down VM
D/BackupManagerService( 2061): Full backup pass complete.
```